# memory management similar to std::shared_ptr without atomic features?

Tags: c++, c++17

Lets say that I have an object which is expensive to copy, and I cannot move it. I am passing this object to other objects, which it will be a member of. I am not able to take a reference/pointer to the original object due to not knowing the lifetime of it.

If I am to instantiate the original expensive object in a std::shared_ptr, I can avoid deep copying the expensive object and am able to pass the object around with it being more efficient than copying the expensive object. Furthermore, it is nicely cleaned up/destructed when the final instance of it goes out of scope. The issue is, copying a std::shared_ptr is expensive, and I would prefer to avoid this. I can create a wrapper for this behavior which initializes a single instance of the expensive object, reference tracks it, and has proper destruction behavior at the last instance of it going out of scope - but I am not sure if there is a easier/more preferred alternative.

Any help here?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "atomic operations ... are expensive" mean, and where did you read this?

Comment: Has profiling actually shown the atomic reference count instructions to be a major pain point, or are you just guessing? 99% of the time they won't matter; premature optimization here means reinventing `std::shared_ptr` without the atomics, which won't be fun. I'll also note: Most of the time, if you're just borrowing a reference you know the caller will hold indefinitely, you can avoid any refcnt manipulation by just having such APIs that don't need to take ownership simply accept it by reference, which means no copying, and no atomics for that borrow.

Comment: Sorry, I have *potentially falsely* assumed that the atomic operations are what slows down the copying of std::shared_ptr. Edited the OP to reflect this potential false assumption. I have not profiled the shared_ptr vs. a wrapper which mimics the behavior, but I have confirmed that the copying of the std::shared_ptr is my current bottleneck in terms of performance.

Comment: Atomic operations by a single thread are rather cheap. They only get expensive when multiple threads attempt to access the same data at the same time. You would have to make millions of copies per second for it to really matter, which would mean you aren't doing anything big with the shared object and maybe should share it less, or split it up into cheap sub-objects that you can copy.

Comment: Certainly copying a `shared_ptr` will be slower than copying a dumb pointer, but the difference shouldn't be excessive - certainly not enough to be the bottleneck in your program.  If it were that slow it wouldn't have been accepted into the standard.  Something doesn't smell right.

Comment: If you have so many operations on the object (that it gets relevant for performance), you should also not allocate or deallocate it on the heap each time. Create an std::array with memory for this object type and a counter.  And a linked list of pointers for the next free memory location. The linked list should also be stored inside the array (and not allocate/deallocate on the heap each time). With this you can hopefully solve the `shared_ptr` and heap bottleneck at the same time. Perhaps you find an existing implementation.

Comment: How do you copy the `shared_ptr`? if you do something like `auto my_copy = std::make_shared<MyObject>(*original);` then you copy the object, not the `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 With `make_shared` you initially create the shared pointer *and* the object. You would use the copy constructor with your syntax, which does the copy. You copy the `shared_ptr` with `shared_ptr<MyObject> my_copy = original;` (assuming `original` is also a `shared_ptr`.)

Comment: @Sebastian: That is my point, OP doesn't show code, so misusage might explain

Comment: @Jarod42 oh, you were explaining, not asking

Comment: I am asking for code :-)

Comment: @MarkRansom he might be using a populated container of shared pointers with many elements - in which case a simple iteration through the container with one copy per element might create some runtime overhead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Red.Wave: Though in most iteration cases (where you don't want the atomics because your container won't be accessed by multiple threads at once), you wouldn't need to copy anyway, you'd just iterate by references (possibly `const`) to the `std::shared_ptr`s. The container will own them while you're iterating, so you only need to copy them if your loop is storing them off somewhere.